# JobID and ListID are zero in the SendLog

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have enabled SendLog for about 2 weeks. The SendLog was created with SendLog template and it has 6 default fields and 4 custom fields (`Email, SubKey, Campaign and LoggedDate`). Logged Date is set to 'Current Date' in the SendLog DE. Retention policy is set to 7 days for individual records. I have tested it after enabled it and confirmed it logged my test send job properly so it's working OK for me.

However, some of the records has `JobID` and `ListID` logged as '0'. The problem has eased, dropping from ~4000(~17%) records in the first week to to ~15 (~0.25%) in the second week. The `BatchID`, `SubID` and `TriggeredSendID` are logged properly. `ErrorCode` is null for all of these records. Nothing has logged to the custom fields.

I am trying to work out why and wonder if I have done something wrong causing the problem (or if it's a backend issue and only SF can fix). The SendLog was enabled from the backend by SF Support two weeks ago. Does it just take some time for SendLog to be 'fully' enabled?

Would love to hear your advice. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A value of 0 in the SendLog essentially means the message was not sent.

[OMM](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_what_happens_when_you_click_send.htm&type=5) writes data to SendLog just before sending the message, and in case you see a value of 0 in the JobID column it means it failed to send to that subscriber.

This would happen in case you were trying to send to:

- subscribers that are opted out at account level
- subscribers suppressed by list detective
- subscribers in “Held” status

I don’t think above is documented anywhere officially, I got this info from SF support.

Comment: Thanks Zuzanna. Big fans of your blog sfmarketing.cloud :)

Comment: I'm not seeing sends to held subscribers in the SendLog.  There's definitely and ErrorCode that represents it, but I'm curious if there are any nuances that you're aware of relating to this.